# how to do both return a status code and return to any controller in mvc in c#, .net core

Tags: redirect, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, c#-4.0

I have a POST method in my controller (controller 1). like below.

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> postData([FromBody]dataModel model)
 {
     // do some stuffs and then
     return OK();
 }
```

but before I return OK, I want to send some details to another controller (controller), basically a  redirection.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> postData([FromBody]dataModel model)
{
    // before return the status, I want to send some details to another controller.
    return OK();
}
```

How can I do that. hope your help on this. can we do it using ajax or is there any other way to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to call a Private function instead of redirecting to another controller.
Since as i understand you will return OK() from the parent controller itself.

But if you want to call another controller then you can do it after the current ajax call return a positive response.